# How to apply a function to a variadic argument list and cat them to a tuple

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, variadic-templates, c++17

In the following example, I would like to transform an integer list to a string tuple and return it as a `std::tuple` of `std::string`s. How do I achieve this goal?

```
std::string to_str(int i) {
  return std::to_string(i);
}

template <typename... int>
auto generate_tuple_string(int... ints) {
  // what to do here?
}
```

Ideally, the `to_str()` can be other function that returns the same (or different) types. The return type should be a `std::tuple` concatenating them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe

```
template <typename... I>
auto generate_tuple_string(I ... ints) {
  return std::make_tuple(std::to_string(ints)...);
}
```

?

Comment: @Rakete1111 - D'ho! Certainly not. Thanks.